# Does Reinstalling a product run all the upgrade steps in Generic Setup?

Tags: plone, genericsetup

It seems some steps are not being run. Am I missing the place where I should specify these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No A reinstall of a package runs the `uninstall` profile an then the `default` profile.

**[START UPDATE]**

As @hvelarde commented: It does not automatically run a `uninstall` profile. It could do nothing or do the uninstallation in a different way.

But usually if there is a profile the profile is named `uninstall` and gets called in the install.py's `uninstall` method.

Example:

```python
from plone.addon.config import PROJECTNAME
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName


def uninstall(self):
    setup_tool = getToolByName(self, 'portal_setup')
    setup_tool.runAllImportStepsFromProfile(
        'profile-{0}:uninstall'.format(PROJECTNAME),
        ignore_dependencies=True)
```

More Infos about a clean uninstall can be found on [@keul's Blog post](http://blog.keul.it/2013/05/how-to-make-your-plone-add-on-products.html)

Keep in mind: A plone addon does not have a uninstall functionality for sure.

**[END UPDATE]**

If you apply the latest the default profile, the version is set to specified version in the metadata.xml - Plone can no longer determine if the package needs a upgrade or not, respectively it assumes your package is up to date, since the packe version on the filesystem is equal to the one stored in the DB.

**Install upgrade step**

As long as package upgrade code [follows some guidelines](http://docs.plone.org/manage/upgrading/), the upgrade appears in the Plone Control Panel -> AddOns (http://localhost:8080/Plone/prefs_install_products_form)

You can now hit the upgrade button on the package, which has upgrades

[image]

**Upgrade helpers**

There are several packages, which helps you track new updates and install them.

- [collective.upgrade](https://github.com/collective/collective.upgrade)
- [ftw.upgrade](https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.upgrade) -> Features a nice overview of installable upgrades.
- [collective.recipe.plonesite](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.recipe.plonesite)

Comment: Hmm Thanks... Been using the portal_quickinstaller tool directly

Comment: I updated my answer with some addons, which makes upgrading a plone addons mostly painless :-)

Comment: Just a clarification: uninstalling a package does not run the uninstall profile unless you explicitly declare that using the good old Extensions/Install.py script. You need also to register this using the <five:registerPackage package="." /> directive on the package configure.zcml file.

Comment: Thanks @hvelarde for the important point - I updated the answer.

Comment: What is the best practice? Is reinstall from portal_quickinstaller deprecated?

Comment: I personally try to follow the instructions of @keul's blog post. So a reinstall with quick_installer works perfectly, BUT a reinstall does not trigger upgrade steps. A reinstall of a package may work if there are only configuration changes (GenericSetup xml), But if a upgrade step manipulates persistent objects, a reinstall probably will put your data in a inconsistent state, which may break the addon. So if a package provides uprade steps run them thru the plone control panel, or with mentioned upgrade addon. If there are no upgrade steps, try to reinstall, but make a copy of your DB first.

Comment: imho it's not deprecated, but it's only a convention to make a package reinstall-able/upgrade-able and depends on programmer mood :-) I cannot answer this for sure...